# BigQuery SQL: Group rows with shared ID that occur within 7 days of each other, and return values from most recent occurrence

Tags: date, google-bigquery, grouping

I have a table of datestamped events that I need to bundle into 7-day groups, starting with the earliest occurrence of each event_id.

The final output should return each bundle's start and end date and 'value' column of the most recent event from each bundle.

There is no predetermined start date, and the '7-day' windows are arbitrary, not 'week of the year'.

I've tried a ton of examples from other posts but none quite fit my needs or use things I'm not sure how to refactor for BigQuery

Sample Data;

| Event_Id | Event_Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 010203 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | 040506 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 | 070809 |
| 1 | 2022-01-20 | 101112 |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | 131415 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | 161718 |
| 2 | 2022-01-08 | 192021 |
| 3 | 2022-02-12 | 212223 |

Expected output;

| Event_Id | Start_Date | End_Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 | 070809 |
| 1 | 2022-01-20 | 2022-01-23 | 131415 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-08 | 192021 |
| 3 | 2022-02-12 | 2022-02-12 | 212223 |

Comment: what if you have 10 consecutive days? will you split it on two bundles? first with 7 days and second with 3 days, or because they are consecutive you will have all 10 days in one bundle? you need to provide more real life data with more scenarios

Comment: 10 consecutive days would be split into two bundles of 7 and 3.

The remit is that events that occur within 7 days of each other should be viewed as one event, the earliest event is the starting point for the 7 day period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider below.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION cumsumbin(a ARRAY<INT64>) RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  bin = 0;
  a.reduce((c, v) => {
    if (c + Number(v) > 6) { bin += 1; return 0; }
    else return c += Number(v); 
  }, 0);

  return bin;
""";

WITH sample_data AS (
    select 1 event_id, DATE '2022-01-01' event_date, '010203' value union all
    select 1 event_id, '2022-01-02' event_date, '040506' value union all
    select 1 event_id, '2022-01-03' event_date, '070809' value union all
    select 1 event_id, '2022-01-20' event_date, '101112' value union all
    select 1 event_id, '2022-01-23' event_date, '131415' value union all
    select 2 event_id, '2022-01-02' event_date, '161718' value union all
    select 2 event_id, '2022-01-08' event_date, '192021' value union all
    select 3 event_id, '2022-02-12' event_date, '212223' value
),
binning AS (
  SELECT *, cumsumbin(ARRAY_AGG(diff) OVER w1) bin
    FROM (
      SELECT *, DATE_DIFF(event_date, LAG(event_date) OVER w0, DAY) AS diff
        FROM sample_data
      WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY event_date)
    ) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY event_date)
)
SELECT event_id, 
       MIN(event_date) start_date,
       ARRAY_AGG(
         STRUCT(event_date AS end_date, value) ORDER BY event_date DESC LIMIT 1
       )[OFFSET(0)].*
  FROM binning GROUP BY event_id, bin;
```

[image]

Comment: **binning** will group days within '7-day' window exclusively into a separate **bin** .

Comment: Thank you for this, I've modified it to suit my data structure and I'm just manually verifying the results but it does look to do exactly what I need - amazing reply! Would you mind breaking down the steps for me as there's quite a bit in there that I don't follow, especially the JS Function

Comment: Further comment to say, I've run through some tests and this works perfectly for my needs

Comment: @Hill79,  due to my limited english, it's not easy to explain the logic step by step with ease.  so, kindly check below link with illustration.  hope it helps.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tWVXcT6ivfenclwy7XRQaFPMYZXXH23RKScdbwMb3f0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate you taking the time to do that - I never would have figured this out myself!