# Grouping rows by ID and timestamp into sessions using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm have a dataset like the one below and I'm looking to add the last column to this data.

The logic behind a `session`, is that it groups all rows by `user_id` into one session if they are within 5 days of the first event in a session.

In the example below, the users first event is `2023-01-01` which kicks off the first session. That is, although there is less than 5 days between `2023-01-04` and `2023-01-06`, this is a new session as the 5 day counter resets when it's reached.

```
user_id   timestamp     session
user_1    2023-01-01    session_1
user_1    2023-01-01    session_1
user_1    2023-01-04    session_1
user_1    2023-01-06    session_2
user_1    2023-01-16    session_3
user_1    2023-01-16    session_3
user_1    2023-01-17    session_3
```

My data contains several users. How do I efficently add this `session` column in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
with mydata as 
(
  select 'user_1' as user_id ,cast('2023-01-01' as date) as timestamp_
  union all
  select 'user_1' ,cast('2023-01-01' as date)
  union all
  select 'user_1' ,cast('2023-01-04' as date)
  union all
  select 'user_1' ,cast('2023-01-06' as date)
  union all
  select 'user_1' ,cast('2023-01-16' as date)
  union all
  select 'user_1' ,cast('2023-01-16' as date)
  union all
  select 'user_1' ,cast('2023-01-17' as date)
)
select user_id, timestamp_,
   'session_' || dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by div(df, 5)) as session
from
(
  select *,
     date_diff(timestamp_, min(timestamp_) over (partition by user_id), day) df
  from mydata
) T
order by user_id, timestamp_
```

Output according to your input data:

[image]

The logic here is to find the date difference between each date and the the minimum date for each user, then perform an integer division by 5 on that data diff to create groups for the dates.

The use of dense_rank is to remove gaps that may occur from the grouping, if it's not important to have sessions ordered with no gaps you could remove it and use `div(df, 5)` instead.

Comment: would you try ["2023-01-01","2023-01-01","2023-01-04","2023-01-06","2023-01-10","2023-01-14","2023-01-16","2023-01-21"] ?
I think it should returns session as [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4] but your query returns [1, 1, 1,  , 2, 3, 4, 5] if I didn't test it wrong.

Comment: Ok, I will check soon

Comment: @Jaytiger, I think it's correct [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the date of '2023-01-21' occurs in the fifth group. As you see, according to the OP's expected output the date of '2023-01-06' occurs in the 2nd group, so '2023-01-20' will be in 4th group and '2023-01-21' in the 5th group.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, 6th and 10th, 14th and 16th should be same session, because 6th and 14th is the start of new session?

Comment: Are you assuming the new session starts every 5 day from the first event day by any chance ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I understood from the question.

Comment: I see, what I understand is that new session can start randomly right after previous session ends. Anyway I got your point and thanks for your kind explanation. I've enjoyed reading your query. I appreciate for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be kind of *cumulative capped sum* problem. If I understood your requirements correctly, you might consider below.

I've answered similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223985/bigquery-sql-group-rows-with-shared-id-that-occur-within-7-days-of-each-other) with some [explanation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tWVXcT6ivfenclwy7XRQaFPMYZXXH23RKScdbwMb3f0/edit?usp=sharing) about below `cumsumbin` user defined function.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION cumsumbin(a ARRAY<INT64>) RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  bin = 1;
  a.reduce((c, v) => {
    if (c + Number(v) > 4) { bin += 1; return 0; }
    else return c += Number(v); 
  }, 0);

  return bin;
""";

WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'user_1' user_id, DATE '2023-01-01' timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_1' user_id, '2023-01-01' timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_1' user_id, '2023-01-04' timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_1' user_id, '2023-01-06' timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_1' user_id, '2023-01-16' timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_1' user_id, '2023-01-16' timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_1' user_id, '2023-01-17' timestamp
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(diff), 'session_' || cumsumbin(ARRAY_AGG(diff) OVER w1) session FROM (
  SELECT *,
         DATE_DIFF(timestamp, LAG(timestamp) OVER w0, DAY) AS diff 
    FROM sample_table
  WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp)
) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp);
```

**Query results**

[image]