# Cumulative sum in BigQuery that resets based on its own value

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I need to calculate the cumulative sum of column A and need it to reset back once it reaches a certain threshold. In the below example, I am calculating cumulative sum and reset it back once it reaches 10 or the label changes.

| Label | Value | cumulative_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | 1 |
| One | 2 | 3 |
| One | 4 | 7 |
| One | 6 | 6 |
| One | 3 | 9 |
| Two | 1 | 1 |
| Two | 2 | 3 |
| Two | 1 | 4 |

I have tried the following code in bigquery
SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY label ORDER BY dummy_sequence) as cumulative_sum,

But its not giving the result as intended.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223985/bigquery-sql-group-rows-with-shared-id-that-occur-within-7-days-of-each-other  might help

Comment: Hi @deeni,did the above comment help you?

Comment: Hi @Kiranmathew sorry, no

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [`RECURSIVE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#recursive_cte) to accumulate the values conditionally.

###### Query

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_data AS (
    WITH
    _sample_data AS (
        SELECT 'One' as Label, 1 as Value, 1 as expected_cumulative_sum,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'One', 2, 3,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'One', 4, 7,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'One', 6, 6,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'One', 3, 9,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Two', 1, 1,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Two', 2, 3,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Two', 1, 4,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Three', 5, 5,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Three', 4, 9,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Three', 8, 8,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Three', 7, 7,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Three', 5, 5,
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Three', 4, 9,
    )
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Label) as row_num,
    FROM _sample_data
);

WITH
RECURSIVE calculate_cumulative_sum AS (
    SELECT label, value, row_num, value AS cumulative_sum
    FROM sample_data
    WHERE row_num = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        s.label, s.value, s.row_num,
        IF(
            -- may want to decide between '>' and '>='
            s.value + c.cumulative_sum >= 10,
            s.value,
            s.value + c.cumulative_sum
        ) AS cumulative_sum,
    FROM sample_data AS s
    INNER JOIN calculate_cumulative_sum AS c
        ON s.label = c.label AND s.row_num = c.row_num + 1
)
SELECT label, row_num, value, cumulative_sum
FROM calculate_cumulative_sum
ORDER BY label, row_num
;
```

###### Results

[image]